# Kafka streams key-value state store (RocksDB) has a delayed persistence hence an immediate look up fails intermittently

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, rocksdb

In our Spring cloud stream Kafka stream application, we are storing certain incoming messages in **KeyValueStore** state store

```
Materialized.<Key, Value, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(STATE_STORE_NAME)
                    .withKeySerde(createSpecificAvroSerde(true))
                    .withValueSerde(createSpecificAvroSerde(false))
                    .withCachingDisabled()
```

and immediately in a different topology (same consumer) trying to lookup the key in the state store using the **InteractiveQueryService**

```
interactiveQueryService.getQueryableStore(STATE_STORE_NAME, QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
```

Also disabled the in memory caching using following configurations

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.cache.max.bytes.buffering=0
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.consumer.cache.max.bytes.buffering=0
```

But still, the key look up fails intermittently. The state store in question is only local (one instance) state store and the input topic has only one partition and hence expectation is to find the key even if it is only a single local state store look up.

Are there any other configuration/memory settings we need to use to flush the messages immediately to the disk state store?
Would there be any buffering/caching still happening before the messages are available in the read only queryable state store?
I believe the interactive query service only able to read the state store in RocksDB SST files.

Comment: I would expect this behaviour if a commit hasn't completed. I would actually call this behaviour 'correct' because otherwise you would be reading uncommitted data that could get rolled back. If possible, try not to fight the eventual consistency model and queryableStores are only eventually consistent.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? This is quite strange behaviour and there's no proper documentation anywhere.